# how to compile a project on fyne and golang with images?

Tags: windows, go, desktop-application, desktop, fyne

I have a project where I upload images with the function: "file.Load Resource From Path("resources/img/planets/mercury.png")", but when I try to compile the project with the command: "fyne-cross windows -arch=*" and transfer the EXE FILE where from the current directory, the pictures in my program are not displayed

go build main.go, fyne-cross windows -arch=386
I don't know what I can doing
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I also tried the commands: "fyne build", "fyne install"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “resources” folder is just part of your source code. Fyne (like Go) apps are single binaries and not distributed with assets. If you want to include items like that you should bundle them - “fyne bundle” or “go embed” will sort this for you.

Comment: //go:embed planets/earth_logo.png
var ImageContent []byte

///////////////////

Comment: How I can do it with fyne bundle?

Comment: Just use “fyne bundle” command. You can embed it in “//go:generate” as well https://developer.fyne.io/extend/bundle

Answer (score 0):

To compile a Fyne project with images in Go and ensure they are displayed correctly in your compiled application, follow these steps:

1. **Bundle Images:** First, use Fyne's bundling tool to convert your images into Go code. This makes them part of the binary, ensuring they're always available. In your project directory, run:

   ```bash
   fyne bundle -o bundled.go ./images
   ```

   This creates **`bundled.go`** with a variable for each image.
2. **Use Bundled Images:** Modify your project to use these bundled images instead of loading from a file path. For the image you mentioned, replace:

   ```golang
   import (
       "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
       "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
       "path/to/your/bundled"
   )

   img := widget.NewImageFromResource(resourceExamplePng)
   ```

   with the variable corresponding to the bundled image, e.g., `resourceExamplePng`.
3. **Compile Your Application:** With your images bundled and your application code ready, you can now compile your Fyne application.

   ```bash
   go build
   ```